# Why does Hindus add "Darbha Grass" to every food during moon eclipse?

Tags: practice, eclipse

Today is Moon Eclipse, so my mother added "Darbha Grass" to every food. Why so?

Why Hindus add "Darbha Grass" to every food during moon eclipse?

Comment: Drabha is hair of kurma I.e. Vishnu it will prevent gamma Ray's affecting the food and turning into poison

Answer (score 1):

The ancient Hindus were extremely sharp in observation, observing inputs and outputs. Nowadays this is called science! Darbha grass prevented fermentation (bacteria). So the wise imprinted it in scripture.
Sri Sri conducted experiment and proved it again.

In Apasthamba Dharmashastra in multiple places durbha is used for holy purposes like purification, guarding against or giving respect.It is fragrant. Incidentally in the Rig Veda it was the barhisha , the sacrificial altar to bring the Gods to sit and drink Soma).

In the Linga Puran , Crowning of Nandishwara, Chapter 43....

Nandis father is informed that his boy will live for one year by Mitra Varuna.

Then
12-13. He was sad and he said“Alas! the power of the adverse fate and of the creator!” On hearing his lamentation the residents of the hermitage gathered there in great bewilderment. They evolved amulets and observed auspicious rites to ward off the evil. They eulogised Mahādeva. the three-eyed lord of Umā.

14. They performed homa repeating the mantra of Triyambaka, offering ten thousand times Dūrvā (Darbha grass) soaked in honey, and accompanied by other materials of worship.
15. My father and grandfather lost consciousness. With all their activities ceased, they lamented, fell down as though dead.

From Apasthamba
Patala 1
For any rite or shradha
12. Having kindled the fire, one strews eastward-pointed Darbha grass around it.

Further
Preparation of the praṇīta water
20. To the west of the fire one pours water into a vessel over which one has laid [two grass blades called] pavitrīs, purifies [the water] three times with two northward-
pointed pavitrīs, raises it to the level of the nose and mouth, places it to the north of the
fire on Darbha grass, and covers it with Darbha grass.

Further
Invocation of the Brāhman
21. On the south side he invites a Brāhmaṇa to sit down on Darbha grass.

Further
Preparation of the Ghee
22. One melts the ājya8
, pours it, to the west of the fire, into the ājya-sthāli, over which
he has laid two purifiers, draws coals [out of the sacrificial fire] from the north, puts
[the ājya-sthāli] on them, throws light on it by means of a burning [grass-blade] throws
two Darbha points into it, moves a firebrand round it three times, takes it from the fire
towards the north, sweeps the coals back [into the fire], purifies [the ājya] three times
with two northward-pointed purifiers, moving them backward and forward, and throws
the purifiers into the fire.

From the rite of marriage f/Apasthamba
8. With the next Yajus (M. 1:1:8) he places [a crown of] Darbha grass on her head; on
that, with the next mantra (M. 1;1;9) he places a right yoke-hole; on this hole he lays
with the next mantra (M. 1:1:10), a piece of gold, and bathes her with the next five
verses (M. 1:2, 1-5), [So that the water runs over that gold and through the yoke-hole];
with the next mantra (M. 1:2,6) he causes her to dress in a new garment, and with the
next (M1:2,7) he girds her with a rope [made of darbha grass]...

And many more.
It is conclusive from these and other scripture that darbha is holy , purificatory.